# Converting .ul files

Tags: python, audio

I recently copied a bunch of audio files, which are feedback left during a phone call.

The vast majority of them are mp3, but a small percentage are files ending in a .ul extension, which I believe is ULAW.

I have tried to play them in Audacity and VLC, but get garbled sounds. I suspect they are corrupted, but I'd like to confirm that by attempting to convert them to another audio format.

Would anyone be able to recommend a library to do that?

I know Python has the audioop module but I do not know enough to start messing with the audio data.

Comment: Try ffmpeg, python is not what you need here.

Comment: You can check the file type with http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/ and its command line tool `sndfile-info`. If you want to do that with Python, you can use the [soundfile](https://pypi.org/project/soundfile/) module.